# match words that have numbers in it while ignore words that don't

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a word using regex that has numbers in it, for example: bar12b12 12bar43 44324f b123

and at the same time ignore words that don't: bar foo bar foo

I've been trying to do this for that past hour... no results!!

This is the closest I could get:

[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+

but it doesn't match correctly ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262545/regex-matching-a-word-with-numbers-in-it

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem! and please don't minus questions unnecessarily !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work...

```
/\b\w*\d\w*/
```